# Is it possible to stop pcap-parser before the end of the file

Tags: node.js, parsing, pcap

I've been using npm pcap-parser to, obviously, parse PCAP files.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcap-parser.  Sometimes I am looking at a very large PCAP file and I only need to analyze the first few (hundred, or thousand) packets.

Is it possible to stop the parser from reading the entire file?  The events it emits are packet, end, and error, so I can't figure out how to stop it from going back to get the next packet, every time.  I'd like to be able to tell it to stop, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of answers here, so not sure there is much interest, but just in case, I figured out how to do this.

Assume you are parsing an input file:
var parser = pcapp.parse(inFile);

As the parser begins to scroll through the file and identify packets, you define a function called (for example) "onPacket" to tell it what to do with each packet:
parser.on('packet', onPacket);

At any point as the parser is handling packets, you can remove this listener using the following:
parser.removeListener('packet',onPacket);

That also seems to cause the parser to emit an "end", which will take the code to whatever you have defined for parser.on('end',endFunction)

Reference for handling Events and Listeners is here:
https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_eventname_listener